# Android - How to disable the paste suggestion on top of the soft keyboard

Tags: android

I want to disable the paste suggestion on the soft keyboard in the EditText XML or programmatically.

The thing I'm referring to is the button with "563737" below

[image: soft keyboard with paste suggestion]

Comment: There are hundreds of soft keyboard implementations, both pre-installed and user-installed. Only some will offer clipboard pasting, and there is no guaranteed way of removing clipboard pasting as an option.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the paste suggestion feature on the on-screen keyboard for an EditText element, you can specify the "textNoSuggestions" value for the "android:inputType" attribute in the EditText's XML definition.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
```

Or you can set the inputType property programmatically in code:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```